# Convergence/Absolute Convergence for $\int_{0}^\infty{\sin^{n}\left(x\right)\over x}\,\mathrm{d}x $

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, absolute-convergence

> Prove convergence and absolute convergence of 
>   $$
> \int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin^{n}\left(x\right)\over  x}\,\mathrm{d}x
> $$

I have seen a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2309065/9464) already, however the answers are not that helpful to me.

My Problem: After using "I.B.P" I get stuck in either using Cauchy criteria or finding a function for direct comparison test.

I was able to show that it is not absolute convergent and that it isn't convergent for even numbers. But I don't know how to do it for the odd numbers.

Comment: this integral does not converge on the given interval

Comment: Be careful : this integral does _not_ converge absolutely for $n=1$

Comment: for n=1 it converges, so for sin(x)^n/(x) it must do it too atleast for odd or even numbers

Comment: and i already could find a proof if n=1 but i dont know how to do it for all n

Comment: The way you have written the problem it appears we are to prove that the integral converges for all $n.$

Comment: Could you add the link of the post that you are talking about?

Comment: But that's false; it diverges when $n$ is even

Comment: Yes but I have problems to show this in a formal way because i dont find the needed criteria for showing convergence/divergence

Comment: Find intervals where $\sin^n x>1/2$, and show the integral over these intervals is already infinite

Comment: But my point is the problem is misstated. It should read "for which $n$ is the integral absolutely convergent, and for which $n$ is it only conditionally convergent"

Answer (score 2):

For $n$ even, the integral diverges since we can look at the interval $\left[\frac{(4k+1)\pi}4,\frac{(4k+3)\pi}4\right]$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^n(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&\ge\sum_{k=0}^\infty\overbrace{\vphantom{\frac4\pi}\ \ \ \ \ \frac\pi2\ \ \ \ \ }^{\text{width of interval}}\ \ \overbrace{\vphantom{\frac4\pi}\ \ \ 2^{-n/2}\ \ \ }^{\text{min of $\sin^n(x)$}}\ \ \overbrace{\frac4{(4k+3)\pi}}^{\text{min of $1/x$}}\\
&=2^{-n/2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac2{4k+3}\\
\end{align}
$$
which diverges by comparison to the Harmonic Series.

Absolutely, for $n$ odd, the integral diverges for the same reason as the integral diverges for even $n$. However, the integral converges conditionally for odd $n$.

$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^n(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^n(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^\pi\sin^n(x)\left(\frac1{x+2k\pi}-\frac1{x+(2k+1)\pi}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin^n(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^\pi\sin^n(x)\frac\pi{(x+2k\pi)(x+(2k+1)\pi)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le\frac2{\sqrt{n}}+\frac1{4\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\int_0^\pi\sin^n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac2{\sqrt{n}}+\frac\pi{24}\int_0^\pi\sin^n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le\frac2{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{\pi^2}{24\sqrt{n}}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Estimates Used Above**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin^n(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&\le\int_0^\pi\left(\frac{4x(\pi-x)}{\pi^2}\right)^n\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x\\
&=4^n\int_0^1x^{n-1}(1-x)^n\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=4^n\frac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(2n+1)}\\
&=\frac{4^n}{n\binom{2n}{n}}\\
&=2\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{k}{k+\frac12}\\
&\le2\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{\frac{k}{k+1}}\\
&=\frac2{\sqrt{n}}
\end{align}
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi\sin^n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
&\le\int_0^\pi\left(\frac{4x(\pi-x)}{\pi^2}\right)^n\mathrm{d}x\\
&=4^n\pi\int_0^1x^n(1-x)^n\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=4^n\pi\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(2n+2)}\\
&=\frac{4^n\pi}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}\\
&\le\frac\pi{\sqrt{n}}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is odd, then $\sin^n(t)$ is an odd function. Hence $\int_{-\pi}^\pi  \sin^n(t)\, dt = 0.$ It follows by $2\pi$-periodicity that $\int_0^x  \sin^n(t)\, dt$ is a bounded function of $x.$ Thus Dirichlet's test implies

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{ \sin^n(t)}{t}\,dt$$

converges.